# Is the use of the null entity (e.g &#x0;) valid in HTML5?

Tags: html, entity

I believe the **null entity** (`&#x0;`) is officially invalid in XML. But I have encountered it when processing HTML. (Perhaps to represent a kind of zero-width character?) But is it valid markup and will browsers freak out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not valid HTML5. You can easily see this by running the following fragment through a validator such as [W3C's](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><title>&#x0;</title>
```

Which will result in the following error:

> Line 1, Column 27: Character reference expands to zero.

The specific code points that are not legal in character references are listed in the spec ([W3C HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references), [WHATWG HTML Living Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#character-references)):

> The numeric character reference forms described above are allowed to reference any Unicode code point other than U+0000, U+000D, permanently undefined Unicode characters (noncharacters), surrogates (U+D800–U+DFFF), and control characters other than space characters.