# Why regexp character \0 does not match NULL html special character &#000; in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, null

Why regexp character `\0` (or `\000`) does not match html special character `&#000;` in my text, while it matches well any other html special character like `\001`; for `&#001;` , `\002` for `&#002;` , `\044` for `&#036;` , etc.?

```js
var txtA = document.getElementById('textA').textContent;
var txtB = document.getElementById('textB').textContent;
var txtC = document.getElementById('textC').textContent;

var hasLineBreak = /\010|\n/g;
var hasNul = /\0|\00|\000/g;
var hasDollar = /\$|\044/g;

console.log("\\n: ",hasLineBreak.test(txtA));
console.log("\\0: ",hasNul.test(txtB));
console.log("$: ",hasDollar.test(txtC));
```

```css
#textA{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

#textA, #textB, #textC{
  display:inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #33aaff;
  margin:4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="textA">this is some &#010;text with line break</div>

<div id="textB">this is some text with &#000; null</div>

<div id="textC">this is some text with &#036; dollar sign</div>
```

Comment: That char is `\uFFFD`. Use `var hasNul = /\0|\00|\000|\uFFFD/g;`

Comment: `&#0;` is not a valid entity. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457105/is-the-use-of-the-null-entity-e-g-x0-valid-in-html5 and https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-%28double-quoted%29-state.

Comment: ok thank you, i used `txt.replace(/\uFFFD/g,'\0')` and now regexp `\0` matches NULL in my text.

Comment: But how will you differentiate a true `\uFFFD` from the one you replaced with? It seems there should not be `&#000;` in your code in the first place.